# Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect

Tags: php, laravel, array

Tengo una pagina de consultas de tramites, donde la misma trae todos los tramites iniciados y una vez selecciono un tramite trae todos los datos del mismo, el usuario si quiere puede agregar una observación y adjuntar imágenes al tramite en cuestión. Cuando creo el tramite guardo el nombre de las imágenes en un array, el campo en la base de datos se llama URLImg y me guarda los datos de la siguiente manera: `["imagen1", "imagen2", "imagen3"]`. Por lo tanto mi idea era agregar las nuevas imágenes que el usuario adjunta con un array_push() y que se sumen los elementos a la lista del array, sin perder las anteriores

Mi problema esta cuando el usuario carga imágenes me sale el siguiente error:

> "Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Tramite::$URLImg has
> no effect"

```
$tramite = Tramite::find($RComunicInter_ID);

$img_array = array();
array_push($img_array, $tramite->URLImg);
//Pregunto si el tramite tiene imagen
    if($request->hasFile('URLImg')){
        foreach($request->file("URLImg") as $image){
            if($image->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'pdf'){
                $name = intval($tramite->NroTramite) . '-' . Str::random(5). '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                array_push($img_array, $name);
                $tramite->URLImg = $img_array;
                $path = 'storage/img/';
                $image->move($path, $name);
            }else{
                $name = intval($tramite->NroTramite) . '-' . Str::random(5). '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = 'storage/img/' . $name;
                array_push($img_array, $name);
                $tramite->URLImg = $img_array;
                Image::make($image)->resize(600, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($path);
            }
        }
        $tramite->save();
        $tramite->ObservacionWeb = $tramite->ObservacionWeb . $request->ObservacionWeb . '%;';
        return response()->json($tramite, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Exactamente ¿por que haces esto `$tramite->URLImg = $img_array;`? podrías explicar esa linea por favor; ¿no debería asignarle un item de ese **Array** como `$tramite->URLImg = $img_array[0];`?

Comment: Hola @Josbert y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ver esto. Hago eso para que guarda en mi campo URLImg el array que estoy formando, ya que sino no me guardaría nada y volvería a tener siempre las mismas imágenes

Comment: Okey okey, ¿pero de que tipo es ese campo `URLImg` en tu base de datos? porque estas intentando insertar directamente un `Array` en el; a menos que sea de tipo **JSON** y tengas configurado el **casting** en tu **modelo**

Comment: El mismo es un campo tipo string

Comment: Échale un ojo a [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186679/15429896), aun así me parece extraño que intentes hacer `insert` de un **Array** en un campo de tipo **VARCHAR** como mencionaste, podrías ver eso también

Comment: Le voy a pegar un ojo, muchas gracias!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127948/discussion-between-elio-farac-and-josbert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes modificar el objeto de esa manera

Básicamente cuando haces esto

```
$tramite = Tramite::find($RComunicInter_ID);
```

Internamente se llama al método mágico __get() que devuelve una copia del valor de cada atributo. Por lo tanto, cuando agregas un elemento a esa copia con array_push, solo estás agregando las imágenes a la copia, no al atributo original.

Es por eso que recibes un error que dice que lo que sea que estés haciendo, no tendrá ningún efecto.

Lo que puedes hacer para modificarlo es, que después de crear el array de las imágenes como hiciste antes, invoques el método insert o update  sobre el tramite:

```
$tramite->update([
 'URLImg' => $img_array
]);
```